# Right way to add new block

Tags: contract-development, ether

I have a contract deployed on Rinkbey which stores some information. Now, I want to create a new block every time a write a data to contract. I am calling send() method of web3 to instantiate a block on every call and I am getting transaction ID for every block. And Later by using that transaction ID I am able to view the data stored on blocked.
Is it the right way?

Answer (score 3):

Since Rinkeby is a public network, you don't need to worry about block creators. Blocks will automatically be mined by miners on the network, so all you have to do is submit transactions (`send()`) to the network.

Comment: Thank you. Is it the right way to store users information i.e by submitting transactions (send()) to the network and not by storing data on contract directly?